# Is there code that i can use to eliminate a runtime error?

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

In my database (access 2010) there is a "Main menu" form that opens up an event form sourced by the event table after a search from an unbound textbox. Up until the most recent Windows update on 4/10/19 the code was working perfectly to create a new record in the event form. Now I get run-time error 2427 (You entered an expression that has no value). What change in code should be implemented to remove the error?

The debugger breaks in Private Sub Form Load() of the event form in the first If statement which is referencing a true/false control.

I have tried with no luck 1. changing the values to (True/False), 2. adding Me. to the beginning of the if statement, 3. removing the if statements from the form load altogether and setting focus to another control on the form and 4. adding a form current event with the code that was previously in the form load event.

This code closes the "Main Menu" form and opens the events form in add mode.

```
Private Sub cmdAddEvent_Click()
    cmdAddEvent.SetFocus
    cboEvent.Value = ""
    blnAddEvent = True
On Error GoTo Err_cmdAddEvent_Click
    DoCmd.Close

    ' wipe out event variables when finding or adding another event
    strSaveYearCode = "": strSaveProjectCode = "": strSaveActivityCode = "":strSaveProposalCode = ""
    g_strEventYear = "": g_strEventProject = "": g_strEventActivity = "": g_strEventProposal = ""
    ' end of wipe-out

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEvents", , , , acFormAdd
    'DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

Exit_cmdAddEvent_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdAddEvent_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    blnAddEvent = False
    Resume Exit_cmdAddEvent_Click
End Sub
```

This is the code in from the events form that the debugger breaks at before the run-time error appears.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If proContentApprove = -1 Then ---This line
        proDescription.Locked = True
        proAudience1.Locked = True
    Else
        If proContentApprove = 0 Then
            proDescription.Locked = False
            proAudience1.Locked = False
        End If
    End If
```

When an record is already in the source table the event form opens without incident. I expect the events form to open as it normally does when trying to add a new record as well.

Comment: Does frmEvents code module include `Option Explicit` in its Declarations section?  If not, add it.  Then does the code compile without error?  (from the VB editor's main menu, Debug -> Compile)

Comment: @HansUp Yes, Option Explicit is included in the module. The code was not compiling without error and then miraculously yesterday everything worked fine with no errors occurring.